# Runnig shell command on osgi/kura stack

Tags: shell, osgi, kura

How I can easily run shell command like `ls` on linux os behind kura?

I've tried classic java approach, but it not work.

Please help. Give me some guidelines, directions. It is very hard to find something on network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use : org.eclipse.kura.executor.Command and org.eclipse.kura.executor.CommandExecutorService.